# Strange behavior with sum() MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I try to make this sum but the result is weird !

**Table structure : solde_user**

```
id      int(10)
date    datetime
solde   varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci
id_user int(10°
```

**Data inside**

```
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
|   id   |        date         |  solde   | id_user |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
| 127536 | 2020-12-15 03:26:02 | 465.0700 |   102   |
| 127311 | 2020-12-14 03:26:02 | 465.0700 |   102   |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
```

**my request**

```
SELECT * FROM `solde_user` WHERE id_user = 102 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Return**

```
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
|   id   |        date         |  solde   | id_user |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
| 127536 | 2020-12-15 03:26:02 | 465.0700 |   102   |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+
```

**if i write this request**

```
SELECT id_user, SUM(solde) as sum FROM `solde_user` WHERE id_user = 102 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

**the return is so weird - WHY ??!!!!**

```
+---------+--------------------+
| id_user |        sum         |
+---------+--------------------+
|   102   | 405292.13999999996 | 
+---------+--------------------+
```

The return is same if i put limit to 2
I don't understand why ??? :(

Comment: The first thing you should learn is how to use SUM().  Of course it will give you the same answer.  It sums all the rows in the table.  No matter what limit you put, it will return only 1 row.

Comment: "Strange behavior with SUM()" There's nothing strange with the behaviour.  It works as expected.

Comment: What your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `group by` clause to make your code a valid aggregation query. Then, you should not be storing numbers as strings. Finally, `order by` and `limit` makes little sense in your context. It applies after aggregation, while your code is meant to return at most one row.

```
SELECT id_user, SUM(solde + 0) as sum_solde
FROM `solde_user` 
WHERE id_user = 102 
GROUP BY id_user
```

`solde + 0` forces the conversion to a number.